# how to filter data based on date - finding daily expenses

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have data in excel and trying to make report as follow.

### [Below data at Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArQa-CwC41L1dHVscU9TQm1FVUlfemVVLWpEWGp4Y3c)

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Col A  +  Col B      +  Col C  +  Col D  +  Col E  + ..... + Col AQ  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Price  + Quantity    + Total   +  Jan 1  +  Jan 2  + ..... + Jan 31  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+        +=sum(D3:AQ3) +=B3*A3   +         +         + ..... + Jan 31  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1     +  7          +   7     +    2    +     5   +.................+
+ 0.568  +  7          + 3.976   +    3    +     4   +.................+
+ 0.345  +  20         +   6.9   +    12   +     8   +.................+
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                      + =SUM(C3:C5) +                                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                      + 17.876  +    ??   +    ??   +.................+
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

In `Col A`, I have price of product.

In `Col D`, `Col E`, I have dates of that month and for each date I am putting number of that product bought.

`Col B` is the total of that month for the respective product. So I have used formula as `SUM(....)`

`Col C` is holding the amount that is spent on that product.

In `Col C`, at the last, I have total of Expenses  did for that month.

Now what I want is, from `Col D` onwards, I want Total of expenses for that day only.

I know I can do it by writing formulae `=(D3*A3)+(D4*A4)+(D5*A5)`, but that would be very ugly as I have 235 rows in my data.

Is there any other alternative for this?

Any idea/ suggestion would be appreciated.

**Note**  ***I don't want to write MACRO for this and get it done. Any pre-defined excel functions would be helpful.***

### [Above data at Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArQa-CwC41L1dHVscU9TQm1FVUlfemVVLWpEWGp4Y3c)

Comment: @NYCCanuck : Can you give demo how can be done using SUMIF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sumproduct` function will do exactly what you need. In your example spreadsheet, enter in `D7` the formula `=sumproduct($A4:$A6,D4:D6)` and then copy to the following columns.